# How to handle shared column with jpa/hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm storing money/currency stored in the database which I want to map using JPA/Hibernate but one column is needed for two different mappings on the same entity.

DB Schema:

```
id: number
currency_code: string
total: number
sub_total: number
```

POJOs:

```
public class MyEntity {
    private long id;
    private Money total;
    private Money subTotal;
}

public class Money {
    private  CurrencyCode currencyCode;
    private  BigInteger value;
}
```

The problem I'm hitting with JPA/Hibernate is that the `currency_code` is needed to be mapped with both `total` and `subTotal`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Type(type = "customMoneyType")
    @Columns(columns = {
            @Column(name = "currency_code"),
            @Column(name = "total"),
    })
    private Money total;

    @Type(type = "customMoneyType")
    @Columns(columns = {
            @Column(name = "currency_code"),
            @Column(name = "sub_total"),
    })
    private Money subTotal;
}
```

which leads to `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity`

Both fields need to be updatable and nullable. The sharing of the column is legacy but not changeable in the near future.  With that said, I'm open to less than ideal solutions which could work until the DB schema can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `MyEntity` to align exactly to the table. Keep the `currencyCode`, `total` and `subTotal` fields as internal to the class and use OOP encapsulation technique to expose a methods for client work with them though the `Money` value object. Something like :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "currency_code")
    private CurrencyCode currenyCode;
    
    @Column(name = "total")
    private BigInteger total;

    @Column(name = "sub_total")
    private BigInteger subTotal;


    public Money getTotal(){
      return new Money(currenyCode, total);
    }

    public Money getSubTotal(){
      return new Money(currenyCode, subTotal);
    }

    public void updateTotal(Money m){
        this.currencyCode = m.getCurrenyCode();
        this.total = m.getValue();
    }

    public void updateSubTotal(Money m){
        this.currencyCode = m.getCurrenyCode();
        this.subTotal = m.getValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've looked at readonly columns, the problem is that both fields are nullable.  If only have the data for the read-only marked one, then i'm stuck.

Comment: I see . Please see my update answer.

Comment: FYI: I didn't use this particular solution because there was a bit of complexity I left out of this question for simplicity, but I would have.